# New way of connecting signals and slots

Tags: c++, qt

I am having a problems with the following line of code:

```
connect(m_uaProxy, CUaProxy::uaItemChanged,this, CUaHandler::onUaMsgReceived);
```

I am using Qt 5.11.1. On windows this compiles and works but yields the following "Issue":

> error: call to non-static member function without an object argument

Running the same code on linux is not possible, because this exact line is terminating the compilation.
I think I am running the code correctly using the new signal/slot connection method. What could be the case in here?

The method definitions are:
The signal in the connection creating class:

```
void uaItemChanged(const MsgType msgt,
                   const QVariant& index,
                   const QVariant& value);
```

The slot in the `CUaProxy` class:

```
void onUaMsgReceived(const CUaProxy::MsgType msgt,
                     const QVariant& index,
                     const QVariant& value);
```

Comment: If you get get an error during compilation on Windows, how does the program "compiles and works"?

Comment: Wait you're saying it compiles and works but the next line you're saying it causes a compilation error.

Comment: I said it causes an "Issue" In qt creator on windows but compiles and works and that this issue causes the compilation to be terminated on linux (not windows).

Comment: you probably should check compilation log instead. Creator took same fallacy-prone path as Visual Studio and began to disguise compilation process by "easy to read" messages in GUI. That message is not related to compilation, it's an output of  static code check done either by Creator or by moc utility.

Answer (score 4):

I got the syntax wrong, this is the correct one (address of the function is needed):

```
connect(m_uaProxy, &CUaProxy::uaItemChanged, this, &CUaHandler::onUaMsgReceived);
```

No idea why it worked on windows platform.

Comment: hmm.. interesting. I thought it shouldn't work. Did you compile on windows using gnu-compatible compiler or was that Visual Studio. My impression was that Qt overloads operator& for QObject members?

Comment: The former (mingw).

Comment: It "worked" because the compiler let you get away with using a syntax extension that makes this C++ expression work with C-like syntax.